# how to use colspan in VF pages

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

i have a VF page code

```
            <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false"  columns="2" >

                <apex:inputField value="{!Opp.field1__c}"/> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!Opp.field2__c}"/> 
                <apex:outputField value="{!Opp.field3__c}"/>    
                <apex:outputField value="{!Opp.field4__c}"/>    
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

I want to have a command button inside the blockSection. Can we have something like a colspan on table to merge the first line to a single column to hold the command button?

Thanks
Prady

Comment: Please make sure to mark your questions as answered that have been answered correctly Prady, or make comments explaining why you don't feel the answer(s) are correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pageBlockSection` renders as a `table` inside a `div`, so once you are "inside" you can just piggyback on that schema (at least until they change how they render sections). You need two columns per section column (in your case 2x2=>4). Use the following

```
<apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false"  columns="2" >
   <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
         <apex:commandButton ...>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <apex:inputField value="{!Opp.field1__c}"/> 
   <apex:inputField value="{!Opp.field2__c}"/> 
   <apex:outputField value="{!Opp.field3__c}"/>    
   <apex:outputField value="{!Opp.field4__c}"/>    
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```